# How to add text responses to selected suggestion chips on Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I added suggestion chips to the Dialogflow Chatbot, but I want them to continue with an existing flow based on the button selected. How can I achieve that?

For example: How else can I help you?
             Locate store    Choose an item       About Us

I would like the user to go these flows which already exist.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would make each of these choices a new Intent, and take action based on that Intent being triggered. Intents represent a specific activity by the user - typically something said or entered, or a selection chip being selected. Suggestion chips are handled just like the person entered what was on the chip.

However, keep in mind that these are just *suggestions*. Users can enter whatever they want. You need to be prepared for them to take the conversation in a different direction or skip ahead in the conversation. For example, in response to your prompt above, they may try to send feedback, or they may enter something like "find a store near me" and ignore the suggestion chip. You need to account for this when designing your conversations and Intents.

Comment: Thank you! Clearly explained, Is there a way I could connect to you for fulfillment-related queries. I need to capture the name and mobile number of users before they start the conversation. Similar queries to get a web rich chatbot.

Comment: If this answer has helped, upvoting and/or accepting it are always appreciated. If you have new questions - go ahead and post a new one on StackOverflow rather than asking it in comments.